# Excel: Organize contact info into columns of similar data

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a list of contact info for customers, each with different amounts of email addresses, cell numbers, and home numbers. I want to have a separate column for each piece of data. How can I achieve that?

[image: Example of what I have and what I need]

Comment: Welcome to the site, Sam! Can you provide more details, please? For example, what is the max number of e-mail addresses a person can have? Max number of cell numbers? Home numbers? Also, is every single name unique when you combine the first name with the last name?

Comment: In order for me to know the max amount of email addresses or cell numbers I'd have to count it manually and there's about 700 names, so I don't have answer to that, sorry. The answer to the second question is yes, every name is unique.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably try to transpose it into columnsand sort by name.

Then, use a countifs formula to count the number of occurrences for emails,cells,etc for each person in another column.

Since there are brackets in the beginning of each data point I would pull out the description needed.  Something like this if the data started in A4

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE("[" & A4&REPT(" ",6),"]",REPT(",",255)),2*255,255),",","")
```

So now the data looks like

```
TOM [EMAIL]oiujoijwaoiejf [EMAIL]
TOM [EMAIL]odfaefsdff     [EMAIL]
TOM [CELL]oiujoijwaoiejf  [CELL]
```

Then do a countifs to count how many of each combination there are.

```
=Countifs($A$4:A4,A4,$C$4:C4,C4)
```

Now the data looks like this.

```
TOM [EMAIL]oiujoijwaoiejf [EMAIL] 1
TOM [EMAIL]odfaefsdff     [EMAIL] 2 
TOM [CELL]oiujoijwaoiejf  [CELL] 1
```

Then you can concatente the Email and Cell together so the data looks like this

```
TOM  [EMAIL]oiujoijwaoiejf  [EMAIL]  1  [EMAIL] 1
TOM  [EMAIL]odfaefsdff      [EMAIL]  2  [EMAIL] 2
TOM  [CELL]oiujoijwaoiejf   [CELL]   1  [CELL]  1
```

Then I would pivot on that data and paste it however you like.

Sorry this was a quick write up and didn't test it but it might work.  You could do it with less columns and more complicated formulas but this should work IMHO.

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly what you meant but it gave me an idea and it worked! Thanks!